# I am trying to run mobile version of the Angular project using yarn and I am continuously getting errors related to @types/lodash-es

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular cli version 13.0.2

my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "hrconnex",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --localize",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "int:extract": "ng extract-i18n --output-path projects/elements/src/locale"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/elements": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.3",
    "@fireflysemantics/join": "^1.0.3",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.5.0",
    "document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.18.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "mobx": "^6.1.4",
    "mobx-angular": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "11.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.186",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.14.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Trying to run the mobile version of the Angular code using yarn - 1.22.19
Getting below errors

```
Error: node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1025:21 - error TS1110: Type expected.

1025         : K extends `${number}`
                         ~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1026:24 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

1026             ? 'length' extends keyof T
                            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1026:38 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1026             ? 'length' extends keyof T
                                          ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1027:26 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

1027                 ? number extends T['length']
                              ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1028:30 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

1028                     ? number extends keyof T
                                  ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1028[0m:44 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1028                     ? number extends keyof T
                                                ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1031:21 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected. 

1031                     : undefined
                         ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1043:41 - error TS1110: Type expected.

1043     type GetFieldType<T, P> = P extends `${infer Left}.${infer Right}`
                                             ~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1043:50 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

1043     type GetFieldType<T, P> = P extends `${infer Left}.${infer Right}`
                                                      ~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1043:55 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected. 

1043     type GetFieldType<T, P> = P extends `${infer Left}.${infer Right}`
                                                           ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1043:57 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1043     type GetFieldType<T, P> = P extends `${infer Left}.${infer Right}`
                                                             ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1043:64 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1043     type GetFieldType<T, P> = P extends `${infer Left}.${infer Right}`
                                                                    ~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1046:29 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1046             : Left extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                                 ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1046:30 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1046             : Left extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                                  ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1046:37 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1046             : Left extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                                         ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1046:48 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1046             : Left extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                                                    ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1046:55 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1046             : Left extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                                                           ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1053:26 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1053             : P extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                              ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1053:27 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1053             : P extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                               ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1053:34 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1053             : P extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
[0m                                      ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1053:45 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1053             : P extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                                                 ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1053:52 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1053             : P extends `${infer FieldKey}[${infer IndexKey}]`
                                                        ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1307:23 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1307          * Checks if `path` is a direct property of `object`.
                           ~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1307:54 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1307          * Checks if `path` is a direct property of `object`.
                                                          ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1312:30 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1312          * @returns Returns `true` if `path` exists, else `false`.
                                  ~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1312:40 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1312          * @returns Returns `true` if `path` exists, else `false`.
                                            ~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1312:60 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1312          * @returns Returns `true` if `path` exists, else `false`.
                                                                ~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1346:23 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1346          * Checks if `path` is a direct or inherited property of `object`.
                           ~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1346:67 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1346          * Checks if `path` is a direct or inherited property of `object`.
                                                                       ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1351:30 - error0m TS1005: ';' expected.

1351          * @returns Returns `true` if `path` exists, else `false`.
                                  ~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1351:40 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1351          * @returns Returns `true` if `path` exists, else `false`.
                                            ~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1351:60 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1351          * @returns Returns `true` if `path` exists, else `false`.
                                                                ~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1751:16 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1751          * to `undefined`. Array and plain object properties are merged recursively.
                    ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1756:43 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1756          * **Note:** This method mutates `object`.
                                               ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1761:30 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1761          * @returns Returns `object`.
                                  ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1842:33 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1842          * This method is like `_.merge` except that it accepts `customizer` which
                                     ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1842:66 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1842          * This method is like `_.merge` except that it accepts `customizer` which
                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1844:28 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1844          * properties. If `customizer` returns `undefined` merging is handled by the
                                ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1844:49 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1844          * properties. If `customizer` returns `undefined` merging is handled by the
                                                     ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1845:33 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1845          * method instead. The `customizer` is invoked with seven arguments:
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1852:30 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1852          * @returns Returns `object`.
                                  ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1938:29 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1938          * The opposite of `_.pick`; this method creates an object composed of the
                                 ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1939:56 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1939          * own and inherited enumerable properties of `object` that are not omitted.
                                                            ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2000:29 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2000          * The opposite of `_.pickBy`; this method creates an object composed of the
                                 ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2001:56 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2001          * own and inherited enumerable properties of `object` that `predicate`
                                                            ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2001:70 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2001          * own and inherited enumerable properties of `object` that `predicate`
                                                                          ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2051:54 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2051          * Creates an object composed of the picked `object` properties.
                                                          ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2093:47 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2093          * Creates an object composed of the `object` properties `predicate` returns
                                                   ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2093:67 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2093          * Creates an object composed of the `object` properties `predicate` returns
                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2443:33 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2443          * This method is like `_.update` except that it accepts `customizer` which is
                                     ~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2443:67 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2443          * This method is like `_.update` except that it accepts `customizer` which is
                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2444:47 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2444          * invoked to produce the objects of `path`.  If `customizer` returns `undefined`
                                                   ~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2444:59 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2444          * invoked to produce the objects of `path`.  If `customizer` returns `undefined`
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2444:80 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2444          * invoked to produce the objects of `path`.  If `customizer` returns `undefined`
                                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2445:65 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2445          * path creation is handled by the method instead. The `customizer` is invoked
                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2448:43 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2448          * **Note:** This method mutates `object`.
                                               ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2456:30 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2456          * @returns Returns `object`.
                                  ~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash-es/node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts[0m:2581:1 - error TS1160: Unterminated template literal.   

2581
```

"@types/lodash": "4.14.186",
"@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.12",
"typescript": "~4.0.2" - tried other versions too compatible with typescript version.- 4.17.4, 4.17.5,  4.17.6,  4.17.7,  4.17.8... up to 4.17.12

Comment: Were u able to find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same error